# how do i populate salesforce record values on external website

Tags: website-integration

i have one button on Lead. This button redirect to one website. By redirecting it is checking the user session on site. If the user is not logged in, signup will appear. Here i want user details from salesforce to populate on site. How can i acheive this?

Comment: You are at the mercy of the external site and what it can accept

Comment: As you are trying to populate User details from Salesforce then, why is the button on Lead?

Comment: from button we are redirecting to the wesite